# Case/Switch statement not executing part of the code in C#

Tags: c#

I have written a Switch/Case statement. The purpose of this statement is to check whether a specific checkbox is selected or not. If the checkbox is selected, the case statements get the `true` value and the name of the checkbox. For example, if I select `Ford` in the XAML front end interface, a label gets updated and it adds the value of 10 and if it is unselected, it subtracts 10 as to get the value back. However, I'm just getting the value subtracted. Even when I select the checkbox, I end up with -10, -20 etc values.

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this.

```
public static int storage = 0;
public static void StorageRequired(string carName, bool state)
{
    switch (carName)
    {
        case "Ford":
            if (state)
            {
                storage += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                storage -= 10;
            }
            return;
        case "Honda":
            if (state)
            {
                storage += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                storage -= 10;
            }
            return;
        case "McLaren":
            if (state)
            {
                storage += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                storage -= 10;
            }
            return;
        case "Mercedes":
            if (state)
            {
                storage += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                storage -= 10;
            }
            return;
        default:
            storage = 0;
            return;
    }
}
```

Now I have a some checkboxes such as `Ford`, `Honda` etc, one for each case. And I am calling them `StorageRequired` method like this:

```
private void Single_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InstallFord?.IsChecked == true)
    {
        InstallAE.IsChecked = true;
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Ford", true);
    }
    if (InstallFord?.IsChecked == false)
    {
        InstallAE.IsChecked = false;
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Ford", false);
    }
    if (InstallHonda?.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Honda", true);
    }
    if (InstallHonda?.IsChecked == false)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Honda", false);
    }
    if (InstallMcLaren?.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("McLaren", true);
    }
    if (InstallMcLaren?.IsChecked == false)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("McLaren", false);
    }
    if (InstallMercedesvisitor?.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Mercedes", true);
    }
    if (InstallMercedesvisitor?.IsChecked == true)
    {
        CarConfigs.StorageRequired("Mercedes", false);
    }
    lblRequiredSpace.Content = $"Required space: {CarConfigs.storage} Mb";
}
```

The problem is that when I click and check a checkbox, for instance `Ford`, I get `-10` instead of `10`. And then when I uncheck it again, I get `-20`. I'd really appreciate some help in figuring out where I am going wrong here. Basically, I should get `10` added if I am checking any of the cars and similarly, `10` subtracted to get back to original value if that car is unchecked.

Note: 10 is just arbitrary here to make things simple.

Comment: If you have e.g. Ford checked, but all other unchecked, you will first add 10 (for Ford), then subtract 10 three times (for the others)

Comment: `StorageRequired` is not used anywhere. But more important: it is static void, so doesn't return anything and modifies a static variable outside of the method. This sounds like a bad idea since all your forms share the same value. The variable and the method should not be static, or let the method be static but return that value.

Comment: I have fixed the mistake. `StorageRequired` and `GetSpaceConsumed` are the same

Comment: if (InstallHonda?.IsChecked == false) will execute as well.  Same for the others, you'll subtract too much.  As-is, you'll have to pay attention to *sender*.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh yes, you're right. Since all of this is in just one sender, the false checkboxes states will be checked as well and therefore it will subtract too much.

Comment: typo: you are checking twice for `InstallMercedesvisitor?.IsChecked == true`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem. Never put return in a switch case, you should use break; instead of return.

I am not really sure what CarConfigs.GetSpaceConsumed is, So I will assume that its a number. So if you are getting a number you should (You don't have to but I reccomend) use return functions.

So this should probably work, however I made the storage to be local variable so it will return number from the switch statement and the whole function in this case would a return function.

```
public static int StorageRequired(string carName, bool state)
{
   int storage = 0;
    switch (carName)
    {
        case "Ford":
            if (state){
                storage += 10;
            }else{
                storage -= 10;
            }
            break;
        case "Honda":
            if (state){
                storage += 10;
            }else{
                storage -= 10;
            }
            break;
        case "McLaren":
            if (state){
                storage += 10;
            }else{
                storage -= 10;
            }
            break;
        case "Mercedes":
            if (state){
                storage += 10;
            }else{
                storage -= 10;
            }
            break;
    }

    return storage;
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem. Your version behaves exactly the same.

Comment: "Never put return in a switch case" Why not? If there is no more applicable logic when you reach such a case, it makes it clear to the person looking at the code that nothing more will happen inside that method (as opposed to when using `break;`).